# How to send email using SSMTP through Codeigniter on Ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, ssmtp

I am new to SSMTP and Ubuntu, but I have successfully sent emails using the following command:

`ssmtp -t < temp_email_file`

Using PHP in Codeigniter, I'm trying to have my controller run the same command. I know this is not the most secure way to do things, but I'm just trying to generate an email to myself when users of our intranet run a script.

I've tried using the following and tried to echo the results, but I receive nothing back:

```
shell_exec()
exec()
system()
```

I'm out of debugging ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be of help. I’m currently using it on Ubuntu Intrepid.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/84689/

Comment: Thanks so much! All I had to do is change the protocol to ssmtp